# How to declare array with 3 colums and 4 rows

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I declare array that has 4 rows and 3 columns. 2 of the columns is int and the other column is a string.help!

```
        string[, ,] threeD = new string[3, 10, 10];
        threeD[1, 807301, miama]= threeD;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a start, make a class:

```
class MyItem
{
    public int oneInt {get;set;}
    public int twoInt {get;set;}
    public string oneString {get;set;}    
    public MyItem(int oneInt, int intTwo, string oneString)
    {
      this.oneInt = oneInt;
      this.twoInt = intTwo;
      this.oneString = oneString;

    }
}
```

Then make a List to hold 4 classes:

```
var myFourRowArray = new List<MyItem>();
myFourRowArray.Add(new MyItem(1,252435,"first"));
myFourRowArray.Add(new MyItem(2,235423,"second"));
myFourRowArray.Add(new MyItem(3,454335,"third"));
myFourRowArray.Add(new MyItem(4,346435,"fourth"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array of [`Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) like this:

```
Tuple< int, int, string >[] arr = new Tuple< int, int, string >[4];
```

Answer (score 2):

if you doesn't really need an Array you can also use a `DataTable`

simple example

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(int) });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(int) });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(string) });

        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());

        int RowId = 0, 
            ColId = 0;

        //Cell access example
        var Cell = dt.Rows[RowId][ColId];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Multidimensional array with 4 rows and 3 columns
You can Code in the following way:

```
object[,] _multi = new object[4, 3] { { 1, 2, "jj" }, 
                                      { 3, 4, "jd" },  
                                      { 5, 6, "jz" },  
                                      { 7, 8, "jl" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

An array contains items of a single type.

The only way around that is by using a mutual parent type of the item's types as the type.

In this case `object`:

```
object[,,] threeD = new object[3,10,10];
```

That will make you cast the items when retrieving them.

As an alternative I suggest you make a type that holds a row with three properties of the correct types and then make an array of that type.

Unfortunately that will make it harder to address a column but you could use Linq to get the column:

```
var textColumn = list.Select(item.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write own custom data-structure for this.

e.g.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int column1;
    public int column2;
    public string column3;
    public MyObj(int col1, int col2, string col3)
    {
        column1 = col1;
        column2 = col2;
        column3 = col3;
    }
}

public class MyList
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObj> List = new List<MyObj>();
    public void Add(MyObj obj)
    {
        List.Add(obj);
    }
}

public class ProgramTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList list = new MyList();
        list.Add(new MyObj(1, 807301, "miama"));
        list.Add(new MyObj(1, 807301, "Test2"));
        list.Add(new MyObj(1, 807301, "Test3"));
        list.Add(new MyObj(1, 807301, "Test4"));

        //test
        foreach (MyObj o in list.List)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.column1);
        }
    }
}
```